# Rails rake db:seed not creating objects that belong_to another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rake, seeding

In my seeds file I have a bunch of objects which belong_to and object which belongs_to a user.

So I have User which has a Library which has_many books

In my seeds file I set up some books like:

```
book = Book.new
book.attribute = "attribute"
book.save

library = Library.new
library.books << book
library.save

user = User.new
user.library = library
user.save
```

What happens is that a User is created which has the Library as expected, yet no books are created.

When I run rails c and do

```
Book.all
```

I see that there are 0 books.

Why is this happening?

Additionally, I create a pool of books and 5 users, and for each user I assign some of the same books created above to that users library.

However, neither

```
User.find(1).library.books
```

return anything or

```
Book.all
```

return anything.

## EDIT: Fixed a typo of = Library instead of = library

## EDIT: Posting models;

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :create_library, only: [:new, :create]

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  after_create :send_welcome_email

  has_one :library, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Library:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Book:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :author, presence: true
  belongs_to :library
  has_many   :sources
  has_one    :cover, class_name: 'BookCover', dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :cover, BookCoverUploader

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sources, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cover, allow_destroy: true
end
```

## note, to supplement creating a respective bookcover for the book model, I simply pass a value for "remote_cover_url" on the Book model which carrierwave uses to create a BookCover on the Book.

Comment: What do the logs say? Are you violating a constraint on your Book class?

Comment: can you show your models?

Comment: @railsdog when I run rake db:seed in the terminal it doesn't show any output so based on that it does not show any errors

Comment: @Ansar What more would you like to know? It's a Model -> has_one -> Model -> has_many -> Book relationship

Comment: Do you have some validations on your `Book` model? Instead of `book.save` try `book.save!`. Do you get an error when you do that?

Answer (score 1):

As @newmediafreak mentioned, you may have validations on the Book class that prevent it from being saved.

I recommend creating your `has_many` and `has_one` instances *through* the associations:

`user = User.create!
library = user.library.create!
book = user.books.create!(attribute: 'my attribute')`

Using the `Object.create!` syntax will cause errors if there are any problems saving. `Object.save` fails silently.

### EDIT 10:48 PDT

You have a typo/error: `user.library = Library` should be `user.library = library`, but I still recommend creating library and the books through the association.

Comment: unfortunately none of the above methods are working. After running seed the Users are created with their respective libraries, but no Books are saved even when using .save! or doing Book.create!(params_hash_here)

Comment: What doesn't make sense is that in the rails console, seeding data the way I am above works fine where I get a book1, library1, and user1, and do library1.books << book1, then user1.library = library, however in seeds.rb it does not work

Comment: @AdamBronfin It's weird that it works from the console.  I wouldn't hurt to post your code for the three models (at least the associations and validtations).

Comment: So it turns out after following the steps more carefully, the method of creating a book with Book.create(hash) in the rails console works, but then upon exiting and reentering console the book no longer stays even though I explicitly save it and it commits successfully